# Would there be EMF induced in our body due to electromagnetic radiations?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-current, biophysics, induction

The experiments of innovative Faraday and Joseph Henry in USA, conducted around 1830, demonstrated conclusively that electric currents were induced in closed coils when subjected to changing magnetic fields.

Maxwell developed a set of equations describing the laws of electricity and magnetism. Using these equations he derived what is known as wave equation from which he predicted the existence of electromagnetic waves. From the wave equation, Maxwell calculated the speed of electromagnetic waves in free space and he found that the theoretical value was very close to the measured value of speed of light. From this, he propounded that light must be electromagnetic wave. Thus, according to Maxwell, light waves are associated with changing electric and magnetic fields; changing electric field produces a time and space varying magnetic field and a changing magnetic field produces a time and space varying electric field.

Electromagnetic radiations are transverse waves. Transverse waves are moving waves that consists of oscillations occurring perpendicular (or right angled) to the direction of energy transfer.

I have question here. Electromagnetic radiations are transverse waves, which are referred as moving waves with changing electric and magnetic fields. We know that current can pass through skin, muscles, or hair of our body. It is also known that, the minimum current a human can feel depends on the current type (AC or DC) and frequency. A person can feel at least $1 mA$ (rms) of AC at $60 Hz$, while at least $5 mA$ for DC.

I thought that, if electromagnetic radiations are moving around us, the magnetic field must be linking with our body, as a result there must be emf induced in our body which should result in current through our body or else we can expect any conductor to conduct current, because the magnetic field of EMR is continuosly linking with it. If assume visible light it has frequency ranging from $4X10^{14}$ to $8X10^{14}$ which is far greater than $60Hz$ needed to produce current which can be felt by us. So, *would there be emf induced in our body due to electromagnetic radiations?* In reality, if we would had got shock if emf would have been induced in our body. But, this doesn't happen. I don't know whether I am wrong any where, or there is really emf induced. If any is the case please explain.

Answer (score -1):

I think OP meant to find whether the induced current by cosmic energies upon our body might cause our relatively 'conductive' structure to in-turn induce electromagnetic field disturbance into the universe around us.

I'm sure there is a way to compose a set of equations to calculate how much energy might remain to be induced after the suns energy reaches earth and penetrates our eM field and resistive gases, also as a product of our personal conductance factor.

We know we receive the energetic particles that travel at the speed of light, which we know do not remain much more energetic than to cause sunburn..
For whatever reason, we have yet to measure higher energy particles propelled to travel faster than light, which could impart greater force.. So much to assume, so much unmeasured data on this account.

Now, I didn't answer your question, but I find it interesting the sort of missing constituents we can attribute to unobserved phenomena..